# Animate the appending of HTML to an element in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, css-animations, ng-animate

I have a directive that appends a chuck of html to an element in the DOM after the user clicks a button. What's the best way to animate this chuck of HTML as it gets rendered?

The `enter` and `leave` events don't seem to work on this because I am appending using `element.append(myHtmlChunk);`

Any ideas?

Comment: what is use case that you can't use angular to render the html without using your own append? Provide more code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The animations in angular won't work since you are outside Angulars normal DOM manipulation. If you wanted to use it you could use ng-switch or ng-show/hide etc to show the html instead, but I am assuming there is a good reason for inserting it directly.

Still, the basic idea of the angular animations still stand, just use css transitions. Insert the element with the initial class and then update it right away to the final class. So if you wanted to do a *fade in* then you would spawn the element with a class that gives opacity 0 and then immediately set it to a class with opacity 1. And give the class a transition as well of course. Then watch it fade in.